# Should we reset the Execution Policy after installing chocolatey?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, chocolatey

Before installing Chocolatey the ExecutionPolicy is **Restricted**. We have to modify it to **Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned** using administrative rights.
It must be set to **Restricted** by *Windows* for security purposes so after completing the installation is it fine to reset back to **Restricted** ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. The Execution Policy is *only* needed to run the installation script.

However, when installing Chocolatey you only have to set the execution policy for the *process* that is running it:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
```

Note the **Scope** parameter.